# Autocomplete jquery No search results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Не работает `autocomplete`  единственный результат, который я достиг так это получаю `NO search results`.

Потратил 2 дня.

Использую стандартный `jQuery.autocomplete`.

Чую что ошибаюсь где-то с начала описательной части `source`.

Пожалуйста у кого есть готовое решение покажите этот код, если что мне нужно вытащить данные из БД, тк из локального массива с переменными autocomplete работает но это не то что мне надо. Спасибо.

Comment: код не желаете привести в вашем вопросе? или мы должны знать что у вас там написано? Что и как и куда отправляется запрос?

Comment: Василий, смысла не вижу ничего интересного нет в моём коде, на php после запроса имею данные, эти данные кодирую в формат json, и собственно на этом этапе я понимаю что нужно работать с jquery, будет добры помогите на простом примере ибо я 3 дня затратил а примера в интернете не нашёл, а нашёл бы мануал тут бы вопросов не задавал а наоборот отвечал бы, спасибо за понимание

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote странно вы ищите, очень странно, это как крохотный пример использования. Там их полно.

Comment: Конкретный пожалуйста ссылку, либо код оттуда приложить сюда с пояснениями, спасибо! :)

Comment: Там же есть `source code`. Кликните, увидите весь код используемый для скрипта. Ну а так, сейчас и сюда закину, но это будет лишний копипаст

Answer (score 2):

Данные для `jQuery.autocomplete` берутся с помощью этого кода:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {

      }
    });
});
```

Где мы указываем настройки для плагина, такие как:

`source` - ссылка, из которой будут возвращаться данные
`minLength` - количество символов
`select` - функция, вызываемая при выборе элементов в выпадающем списке

Например, если данные приходят в виде

```
[
    {
        value: 'Value1',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        value: 'value2',
        id: 2
    }
]
```

То данные содержащиеся в `ui` можно будет вызывать так: `ui.item.value`, `ui.item.id`

[Ссылка на документацию](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

Comment: Вот смотрите вместо search.php я подставляю свое имя файла, но не работает что я ещё должен дописать прописать? Потому что с этим кодом пока что не работает если что в php я в конце делаю echo json_encoding($myvar)

Comment: Дак а что не работает то? Что вам возвращает сервер? Как вы это возвращаете на сервере? Я ничего не вижу, вы не скинули код.

Comment: Вот что в конце php: echo json_encode($myvar) собственно я это уже писал!:) вывод такой [{"name:"twix"},{"name:"snikers"}... И тд, и перехожу в jquery собственно смысла ваш шаблон писать нет тк я не знаю что туда вписать, название моей кнопки quest a id=searchinDB собственно какие ещё вам данные предоставить?

Comment: Как это не знаете что вписать в `jquery`? Вам данные с сервера приходят? Это можно проверить во вкладке `Network` (Chrome) | Сеть (Firefox) и там найти ваш запрос, и посмотреть вернувшийся результат, если он возвращается правильно, то пишите ваш `jquery` код. И формат возвращаемый должен быть с массивом объектов `value` и `id`

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю вместо value - twix ; name - id ? Видимо значит в массиве проблема что он не выводит так как неверный формат

Comment: вы на вопрос ответьте, что приходит от сервера в `Network`. А по стандарту автокомплит работает с массивом объектов, с парой значений `value`, `id`

Comment: Если вы про это: test_autocomplete.php?item=twix ,то да приходит

Comment: ну да, приходит, скиньте сразу формат в котором приходит, сам результат какой, прямо из нетворка заскриньте

Comment: Мне не удобно скрин высылать, но что вот сидит в echo_json myvar то и распечатывает ничего другого нет пусто

Comment: я ничего не вижу, у меня нет ваших данных, мне не с чем работать, как я могу вам помочь? Вы привели формат своих данных к виду {value: '', id: ''}?

Comment: Да да формат json выводит [ {"" : ""} ]

Comment: это что такое вы сейчас скинули? В чем проблема сделать скриншот с ответом сервера, и возвращаемыми им данными, я не пойму... Я не могу вам помочь, не имея информации. Это как в кромешной тьме стрелять

Comment: Значит давайте ещё раз, опустим запрос sql, допустим есть массив arr: twix,snikers далее я делаю json_encode($arr) всё! Далее я перехожу в jquery так ведь? Вот лучше помогите здесь дописать как правильно...

Comment: Вы совсем не понимаете о чем я говорю, а мне порядком надоело.Вы даже не можете понять за 3+ сообщениях о чем я говорю, о данных внутри объектах, какие они должны быть, из каких полей состоять... Перечитайте ещё раз все комментарии. может в сотый раз вы поймете каким должен быть объект, который должен приходить. И поймете, что я хочу увидеть в нетворке ответ от сервера, это ведь так трудно, нажать 3 кнопки, и отсечь 10 комментариев к ответу

Comment: В броузере json приходит и данные в виде 0 {value: "123"} далее если кликнуть по индексу 0 будет снова {value: "123"} то есть формат вывода не получается видимо

Comment: @Ilenya а идентификатор где?

Comment: Какой такой идентификатор, уточните пожалуйста

Comment: уже неоднократно писал: `{value: '', id: ''}` какие поля должны быть

Comment: А разве Id обязательно должно быть? Так как у меня в массиве который сформирован из sql запроса берётся лишь value, и id лишний/не нужен. И в спецификация нет обязательного требования, вроде же разрешается и одно значение в моём случае "value"

Comment: интересно, как это самый важный ключ, с которым всегда идет связь, может быть не важным. На нем все и держится если что. А так я не знаю как и что там у вас, и я не могу разобраться по удаленке. Учитесь дебажить. Найдите причину того, что не доходит, и не отображается

Comment: Да многие варианты были опробованы, даже если приводил к формату  [{id: "" value:""}] то вывода не было. В последний раз было достигнуто то что выводился пустой список(т.е значения в json есть, а отображение конечного нет).

Comment: ну вы явное делает что то не правильно, пример есть? есть! он работает? работает! Повторяйте и делайте все как в примере. либо дебажте. Я вам не могу помочь

Comment: Пример конечно работает, запускается с лёгостью))

Comment: Василий давайте разберёмся в проблеме до конца) интересно же, что, В нашей жизни/ситуации проблемы  возникают на ровном месте, и из коробки мало и редко когда работают вещи. А именно ситуация проясняется с помощью tcp trace обнаружилось что перед объектом символы-кракозябры возникают, с начало возникали символы характерные BOM, НО я их исправил и ошибка parse error снова возникает, и сейчас такие вот коды перед объектом 1003 и ff4, естесно гуглил, затем в новые файлы на положил код, всё равно Ajax не получается(( как исправить и что может быть сейчас то? Спасибо:)

Answer (score -1):

Итак один из вариантов решения проблемы (помог только мне этот способ, его и описываю):

Используемые библиотеки jquery-ui.css, jquery-1.10.2.js, Jquery-ui.js
НИКАКИХ header!!!

Имеем main файл, пусть имеет имя - index.php , и файл 200.php в котором sql запрос и подключения к бд и вывод echo json_encode($data) - ваша переменная.
Далее в index.php при нажатии на кнопку подключаемся include_once(ваш_путь\200.php); достаточно в body 
И теперь важное - Ajax autocomplete с параметрами URL: `'200.php', type: 'post', dataType: 'json', data: { quest: request.term}`
Далее прописываем только

```
success: function(data) {
Response($.map(data,function(item) { return { label: item.label, value: item.value}
}));
},
```

И  для отображение данных из success это `select: function(event,ui) { ui.label; ui.value;}`
Всё заработает, если возникнут вопросы напишите мне вместе разберём